# Help with verb tense

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, tense-agreement

Which of these sentenses is correct?

- If we stopped the project, they would pick up where we **left off.**
- If we stopped the project, they would pick up where we **would have left off.**
- If we stopped the project, they would pick up where we **had left off.**

I'm pretty sure that only the first one is correct because "left" should agree with the verb "stop", which is in the past to make the conditional. But I need to be 100% sure.

Comment: Only the first is likely. The second looks like an attempt at "literal translation" from another language that uses "conditional" verbs differently to English (it's a typical "error" from *German* speakers, I believe). The third version is invalid because it lacks the necessary "verb form parallelism" of *If we **had** stopped the project, they would **have picked up** where we **had** left [**off**].* But consider the "Present Tense" alternative, which would probably always mean the same as your first example: *If we **stop** the project, they **will** pick up where we **leave off**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Thanks. Shouldn't it be more appropriate the past tense, though, if I want to convey a more remote possibility, which is what I want in this case? The subject definetely doesn't want to stop the project. By using "if" instead it sounds like the subject is simply considering possible outcomes in a more neutral way.

Comment: Yes, you're quite correct that "past" tense here carries a stronger implication of "far removed from the present, less likely". Which could be even more strongly implied by "subjunctive" *If we **were to stop...***, but not everyone likes to use such "hi-falutin" language. But much depends on whether the speaker himself supports the idea of stopping, regardless of how *likely* he thinks it is.